# Best way to update value from parallel running script - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio

I have two Python scripts (assume **script_1** and **script_2**). **Script_1** scans the network using `subprocess` to call some routines, and updates certain values. Its update rate is slow. It could also be running indefinitely on its own process, in contrast to being invoked. **Script_2** has a main loop that performs a number of different actions, and **some** of the actions depend on the latest status of the values updated by **script_1**. Here is how it shouldn't be done:

```py
### script_1 ###
from time import sleep
import random

# This could also be an infinitely running
# independent task, updating a file/database/whatever
def tedious_task():
    sleep(10)    # working hard...
    value = random.random() * 10
    return value

### script_2 ###
from script_1 import tedious_task
from time import sleep

while True:
    value = tedious_task()  # waiting...
    if value > 5:
        print("Do something")
    else:
        print("Do something else")

    print("Do other stuff")
    sleep(1)
```

As a side note, I do not care about logging the updated values of **script_1**. I just need the latest value.

I have in mind a few different ways that it could be implemented, such as interrupts/callbacks, async, threading, multiprocessing, or even writing on external locations such as files, databases etc. However, most of them are overkills and the rest are just not ideal.

Threading is a potential candidate. I am comfortable using threads, however I've read a lot on how it can destabilize a system if it's not implemented right, and I need this system to be stable for a long time. "Use async IO when you can; use threading when you must", I read somewhere.

Async IO feels a bit of an overkill (not as much as using a database), but I may be mistaken. I haven't used asynchronous tasks for many years (and never in Python), so I have forgotten most of it. My main concern is that since I only need the last value returned, if my main routine slows down for some reason, it will lead to a lagging series of returns of an async function. I may be missing something.

So, is there any way that this is preferably done?
This might pass as an opinion based question, however what I really need is an answer based on facts.

Comment: If I understand correctly - `script_1` runs for a long time and then updates/returns a value periodically and `script_2` is triggered by this value being updated? You want `script_1` to go back to running while `script_2` is also doing it's thing?

Comment: `script_2` does not need to be triggered, although it could be a solution. The ideal would be to read the updated value at its own pace. `script_1` should run periodically, so yes it should either go back to running (or just keep on running in case it does not interact with `script_2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiprocessing something like the following should work

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from time import sleep
import random

def producer(v):
    while True:
        sleep(10)    # working hard...
        with v.get_lock():
            v.value = random.random() * 10

def worker(v):
    while True:
        value = v.value
        if value > 5:
            print("Do something")
        else:
            print("Do something else")
        print("Do other stuff")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Value('i', 7)  # See the docs for multiprocessing.Value
    producer_process = Process(target=producer, args=(v,))
    worker_process = Process(target=worker, args=(v,))
    producer_process.start()
    worker_process.start()
```

Comment: This is close to what I had in mind regarding multiprocessing. However, it seems the `worker` gets stuck waiting for `q.get()`, which is exactly what I want to avoid. Is there a way to continue until `q` is set? Also, since I need the last value, what happens when the producer puts more than one value in the queue? The concept of a stack would be more suitable in this situation.

Comment: You want the worker to keep looping with the same value even if the value hasn't changed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or reading the same value if not changed, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can use multiprocessing.Value() to share a variable between 2 processes https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value

Comment: This would create a "variable" that can be written to and read by both processes with no (minimal) blocking. Updated the answer

Comment: That seems to be working! Before accepting your answer, I will read more about it to also give time to others that may have something to contribute. Thanks :)